# C# LAN ネットワーク内にある別PCのファイル操作

Tags: c#, windows, network

- 問題
  現在、2台のPCがLANネットワークで接続されており、片方のPCからもう一方のPC内の特定のファイルを操作(移動)したいと考えています。
  C#のプログラムを書き、実行すると"Access to the path is denied."のErrorになってしまいます。
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プログラムは以下です。

```
string target     = @"\\PCName\c\temp\target";
string originPath = @"\\PCName\c\temp\origin";
var items = Directory.GetFiles(originPath);

foreach (var itemPath in itemPaths)
{
  string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(itemPath);
  File.Move(item, target + "\\" + file);
}
```

移動元と移動先のフォルダをUNCで指定しています。

プログラムを実行するPCと対象のPCのネットワークは設定されており、リモートデスクトップなど別の方法ではアクセスできます。
対象のフォルダはRootを含め`Everyone`で共有しています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
プログラムを管理者権限でも実行しましたが結果は変わりません。

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、ご教授頂けると幸いです。

- 環境
  　OS: Windows7 Pro

Comment: 確認ですが、リモートデスクトップではなく当該共有を使用してExplorerで同等のコピー操作は成功しますか？

Comment: ファイル共有のアクセス権と、ファイル（ディスク）に対するアクセス権は別です。ファイルに対するアクセス権はありますか？

Comment: @sayuri  共有フォルダ設定を行い、コピー操作は可能です。リモートデスクトップでもコピー可能です。

Comment: @user15092 ファイルに対するアクセス権ですね。確認してみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実際に試したわけではありませんが、英語版での [Get files using UNC Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35510378) という質問についた [回答の一つ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286055) を参考に投稿します。

UNC パスの指定を以下のいずれかを試してみてください。

- `@"\share\directory\folder"`   -> `@` を付ける場合、先頭の `\` は一つだけ
- `"\\share\directory\folder"`   -> `@` を付けない場合、先頭の `\` は二つ

Comment: いや `@"\\share\dir\file"` または `"\\\\share\\dir\\file"` であっているはず (UNC path の最初は `\\` だから)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、回答のように指定すると相対Pathになるようでした。